# Не работает JTextArea.getText();

Tags: java

Здравствуйте уважаемые участники форума. Почему-то не работает метод getText(). Подскажите пожалуйста: в чем проблема. Что-то даже нагуглить ничего не выходит.

```
public class ClickListener implements ActionListener{
Integer ids;
Socket s = new Socket();
ClientRegistrator cm = new ClientRegistrator();
VisualFrame vf = new VisualFrame();
String line1 = null;
String line2 = null;
public void variable(Socket socket, Integer id) {
    ids = id;
    s = socket;

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()));
                System.out.println("OutStream on start");
                System.out.println(line1);
                System.out.println(line2);
                Thread.sleep(100);
                line1 = vf.JTA1.getText();
                line2 = vf.JTA2.getText();
                System.out.println(line1);
                System.out.println(line2);

                dout.writeUTF(line1);
                dout.writeUTF(line2);
                dout.flush();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


}



public class VisualFrame {
JFrame jf = new JFrame();
JTextArea JTA3 = new JTextArea(30, 100);
JTextArea JTA2 = new JTextArea();
JTextArea JTA1 = new JTextArea(12, 1);
JScrollBar JSB = new JScrollBar();
public void visual() {
    jf.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    jf.setLayout(null);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setSize(1500, 1500);
    jf.setVisible(true);
    ClientRegistrator cm = new ClientRegistrator();
    ModifyFrame mf = new ModifyFrame(); 
    JTA1.setVisible(true);
    JTA1.setBounds(515, 0, 100, 30);
    JTA1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    JTA1.setLineWrap(true);
    JTA1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
              BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(),
              "",
                    TitledBorder.RIGHT,
                    TitledBorder.BOTTOM,
                    null,
                    Color.blue));
    JTA2.setBounds(515, 35, 100, 100);
    JTA2.setVisible(true);
    JTA2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
              BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(),
              "",
                    TitledBorder.RIGHT,
                    TitledBorder.BOTTOM,
                    null,
                    Color.blue));
    JTA3.setBounds(625, 0, 500, 500);
    JTA3.setVisible(true);
    JTA3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
              BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(),
              "",
                    TitledBorder.RIGHT,
                    TitledBorder.BOTTOM,
                    null,
                    Color.blue));
    JTA3.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    JTA2.setEditable(true);
    JTA3.setEditable(true);
    JTA2.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    JTA2.setLineWrap(true);
    JTA3.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    JTA3.setLineWrap(true);
    jf.add(JTA3);
    jf.add(JTA2);
    jf.add(JTA1);
    jf.add(cm.JCP);
    jf.repaint();

    cm.worker1();




}
```

Comment: Java занимаюсь месяц. Прошу строго не судить)

Comment: А вопросы вы тоже только месяц задаёте? В вашей простыне метода `getText()` вообще нет! И что значит "не работает"? Дома на диване лежит и ящик смотрит?

Comment: Исправился. Не работает - это значит: не выполняет свою функцию.

Comment: А что значит "не выполняет"? В чём это выражается?

Comment: И почему у Вас `VisualFrame` создаётся в `Listener`'е? Похоже, в этом и проблема.

Comment: Мне нужно что бы этим методом считывался текст введенный в JTextArea и отправлялся через сокет клиенту. Пытался посмотреть как работает код, вставляя через каждую строку System.out.println(), что бы увидеть значения переменных. Программа выполняется до участка line = vf.JTA1.getText(); далее просто висит.

Comment: Кажется понял. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Если честно не совсем понял. А как тогда связать listener с JTextArea, которое должно создаваться при запуске программы?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32548/discussion-between-kff-and-lemuur).

Comment: @kff, опубликуйте ответ, пожалуйста, если проблема решена.

Answer (score 1):

И почему у Вас VisualFrame создаётся в Listener'е? Похоже, в этом и проблема.
От @kff
Таким образом проблему решить получилось. Спасибо большое за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вам стоит лучше продумать архитектуру приложения и переименовать переменные.Старайтесь давать переменным осмысленные имена таким образом, что бы из названия переменной было понятно зачем она нужна и где используется, это улучшит читаемость кода.Как пример, есть кнопка, которая отсылает пакет на сервер, назвать её можно примерно так: sendPacketButton.