# Как выполнить JTextArea.getText в ActionListener`e другого класса?

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте уважаемые участники форума. Подскажите пожалуйста: как считать текст из JTextArea по нажатию кнопки? Пишу чат. Когда нажимаю на кнопку ничего не считывается. Пытался выводить на консоль результаты. Выводятся просто пустые строки. Ничего не могу понять.Подскажите пожалуйста. Вопрос этот уже задавал, но так ничего и не получилось.

```
public class Sender implements ActionListener{
String line = null;
String line2 = null;
VisualPanel vp = new VisualPanel();

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            line = vp.JTA1.getText();
            line2 = vp.JTA2.getText();
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println(line2);

}
```

Comment: В вопросе код укажите, который не срабатывает

Comment: Был же [Не работает JTextArea.getText();](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472039/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-jtextarea-gettext), зачем плодить вопросы?

Comment: Я же написал по этому поводу. Так и не разобрался в итоге в чем проблема.

Comment: так у вас все еще vp **создается** в слушателе. Покажите/сделайте минимальный код всего интерфейса приложения, в котором у вас используется этот класс. Хотя наверняка там есть другая VisualPanel, в которую пользователь вводит данные, и вам надо вместо создания передавать ее в слушатель.

Comment: Кажется на этот раз все понял. Спасибо боольшое за ответ. Сейчас попробую сделать так, как Вы говорите.